# IndexError: list index out of range in python, know the meaning, but don't understand why this happens

Tags: python, indexing, range

I have the following code and I call the program writing:

```
python new.py -s 13 -p 5
```

But then, in line 63 I get the following error. I know what it means but I can't understan why.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "new.py", line 63, in <module>
rythm[i].append(rythm[last])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

And there is the code. What I am trying to do is spread 0s equally among 1s. The first input is the length of the string with the 0s and 1s, and the second input is the numper of 1s. Thank you!

```
import argparse


p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument("-pulses", help = "number of pulses", type = int)
p.add_argument("-slots", help = "length of the rythm", type = int)
args = p.parse_args()
slots = args.slots
pulses = args.pulses


pauses = slots - pulses

mod = pauses % pulses

rythm = []


if mod == 0:
    x = slots/pauses
    l = 0
    while l<slots:

        if l%x == 0:
            rythm.append(1)
        else:
            rythm.append(0)

        l = l + 1

    print (rythm)

if mod != 0:
    i = 0
    j = 0

    while i < pulses:
        rythm.append([1])
        i = i + 1

    while j < pauses:
        rythm.append([0])
        j = j + 1

    last = len(rythm)
    last = last - 1
    last_len = len(rythm[last])
    x = slots%pauses
    y = pauses - x

    flag = True

    while flag == True:
        flag = False

        if (last_len != 1) or (rythm[last] != 0):

            flag = True
            i = 0

            while i < x:
                rythm[i].append(rythm[last])
                rythm.remove(rythm[last])

                i = i + 1

            y = y - x
            x = x%y
            last = len(rythm)
            last = last - 1
            last_len = len(rythm[last])

    print (rythm)
```

Comment: One FYI: it's spelled rhythm.

Comment: yeah I thought so and you are write, but it was on the headline of my project and I thought I should use it like this, thank you anyway!

Comment: `rythm.append([1])`... You are adding a list into a list? You have `rythm.append(1)` above that

Comment: yes, because as I know you can have a list like that:
[[1,0,1],[1],[10]] so I thought I could do that
and thats why I use rythm.append([1]), so I will insert 1 into a list in the list as well

Comment: Instead of computing `last` yourself (`len(my_list) - 1`), why not use negative indexing (`my_list[-1]`)? Your way can be wrong. Index -1 cannot (unless your list is empty).

Answer (score 0):

`IndexError: list index out of range` - means that the you are accessing a value by position which doesnt exist.

for example:

```
a = range(10) #length of a is 9, list indices start at 0
print(a[10])  #accessing value by a index that doesn't exist, raises a IndexError exception
```

Comment: Yes I understand and thank you, but in lines 38-44 I create the following list:
[[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]

and then in line 63 I try to insert something in rythm[0] when i=0, which is [1], and I don't know why I can't

Comment: yes but are you sure that there's a value at rythm[last] ?

Comment: Yes because the length of the list is 13, so when I write
    last = len(rythm) - 1
 it means I have the position of the last value of the list, which is rythm[last].
I hope I'm not wrong, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

Should the check here:

```
if (last_len != 1) or (rythm[last] != 0):
```

Be:

```
if (last_len != 1) or (rythm[last] != [0]):
```

Add some debugging, or simple print statements. When you try this:

```
rythm[i].append(rythm[last])
```

There is definitely nothing at `rythm[last]`, because you did

```
rythm.remove(rythm[last])
```

On the last iteration.

Comment: Thank you I checked the if part, but now it does not enter at all at the if section

I cannot understand why these is nothing, because I first insert the value and then I remove it. After that, I change also the last value..

Comment: Using the advise that you all gave to me, it finally worked!! Thank you very very much!